# Using Cell reference in SQL query

Tags: vba, excel

I am using below VBA command to extract data using a SQL query by using a cell reference as filter.

```
Public Sub Run()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Connected As Boolean
    Dim server_name As String
    Dim database_name As String
    Dim Allocation As String

    Sheets("Perc").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.ClearContents


    ' Our query
    SQL = "SELECT Segmentation_ID,MPG,SUM(Segmentation_Percent) AS PERC " & _
          "FROM dbo.HFM_ALLOCATION_RATIO " & _
          "WHERE Segmentation_ID = " & Sheets("Perc").Range("A1").Value & " " & _
          "GROUP BY Segmentation_ID,MPG ORDER BY MPG"

    ' Connect to the database
    server_name = Sheets("General").Range("D1").Value
    database_name = Sheets("General").Range("G1").Value
    Connected = Connect(server_name, database_name)

    If Connected Then
        ' If connected run query and disconnect
        Call Query(SQL)
        Call Disconnect
    Else
        ' Couldn't connect
        MsgBox "Could Not Connect!"
    End If

End Sub
```

But when I run the macro, it's showing a runtime error

> Invalid column name ALO0000274

Here `ALO0000274` is the filter I set in `A1`.

Kindly help to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes to your `where` clause (you're passing a text value, so you need to include quotes):

```
SQL = "SELECT Segmentation_ID,MPG,SUM(Segmentation_Percent) AS PERC " & _
      "FROM dbo.HFM_ALLOCATION_RATIO " & _
      "WHERE Segmentation_ID = '" & Sheets("Perc").Range("A1").Value & "' " & _
      "GROUP BY Segmentation_ID,MPG ORDER BY MPG"
```

(Note the single quotes `'`  that enclose the value you want to filter)

Comment: Thanks I have missed single quotes in my filter... I have set the quotes and I get the result...

Comment: @n8. The example provided in the question is a string, so quotes *are* needed... of course, you could check if the value is a string or a number in the code, and include/exclude the quotes if needed

Comment: Agreed, I was just clarifying as the reasoning for the single quotes was not stated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are adding your single quotes around your string. Have you tried changing your WHERE clause portion of your SQL statement to `"WHERE Segmentation_ID = '" & Sheets("Perc").Range("A1").Value & "' "`